# How to call a function with jQuery blur UNLESS clicking on a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a small jQuery script:

```
$('.field').blur(function() {
    $(this).next().children().hide();
});
```

The children that is hidden contains some links. This makes it impossible to click the links (because they get hidden). What is an appropriate solution to this?

This is as close as I have got:

```
$('.field').blur(function() {
       $('*').not('.adress').click(function(e) {
            foo = $(this).data('events').click;
            if(foo.length <= 1) {
//             $(this).next('.spacer').children().removeClass("visible");
            }
            $(this).unbind(e);
        });
});
```

The uncommented line is suppose to refer to the field that is blurred, but it doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is it that you *want* to happen in this scenario?

Comment: What exactly is your requirement ?

Comment: I would like, that when you click the links those http-requests should be made and a new page should be loaded.

Comment: I'm getting closer. This is what I got so far:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give it a slight delay, like this:

```
$('.field').blur(function() {
  var kids = $(this).next().children();
  setTimeout(function() { kids.hide(); }, 10);
});
```

This gives you time to click before those child links go away.

Comment: this is a nice solution, allthough it needs atleas 50 ms to work, and it get's way to slow!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ended up doing it:

```
var curFocus;
    $(document).delegate('*','mousedown', function(){
        if ((this != curFocus) && // don't bother if this was the previous active element                
            ($(curFocus).is('.field')) && // if it was a .field that was blurred
            !($(this).is('.adress'))
        ) {
            $('.' + $(curFocus).attr("id")).removeClass("visible"); // take action based on the blurred element
        }

        curFocus = this; // log the newly focussed element for the next event
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

I *believe* you can use .not('a') in this situation:

```
$('.field').not('a').blur(function() {
    $(this).next().children().hide();
});
```

This isn't tested, so I am not sure if this will work or not.

Comment: it didn't work but this is definitely the neatest solutions so far!

Comment: This will bind that blur function to all elements which have `class="field"` and are not `<a>` elements.  Not quite what we're going for.